# JS script in theme is ignored for anonymous users

Tags: theming, javascript

It just discovered that my script.js in my theme is ignored for anonymous users. But only on certain pages. When logged in everything works on all pages. When logged out things only work in some content nodes. For example I have a navigation menu outside of the system menu. It's an exposed block from a view, that I use as a navigation menu to mirror the taxonomy (the taxonomy module does not work for me). I use the theme's script.js to collaps and expand menu items as appropriate. But this is ignored when logged out on most pages (but as I said it works when visiting some content nodes). What is this?

I also discovered that flexslider doesn't wok when logged out. But it works in content nodes... I must be missing something.

I have tried adding:

```
drupal_add_library('system', 'jquery', 'ui.sortable', 'ui', 'drupal.collapse');
```

... in my template.php (in template_process_page, and I also tried to add it in template_preprocess_html).
In the Firebug "Net" tab I can see that my script,js is loaded together with jquery and a whole bunch of js files. So if everything is loaded, why is it ignored on certain pages when logged out? Any ideas?

Edited... I also have tried to add break points in my script.js file and it is clear that the script is ignored all together on certain pages.

Comment: Have you checked if those where loaded from somewhere else?

Comment: have you tried that way? drupal_add_library('system', 'jquery'); drupal_add_library('system', 'ui.sortable'); ...

Comment: You mean the librarires... not sure how to check from where they are loaded though.. I try to figure it out in Firebug...

Comment: No, I haven't tried that... I will do that right away.

Comment: No that did not work. Since the files are actually loaded, I can't understand why they are ignored... I keep digging.

Comment: What do you mean by ignored? If there are there then it means the script calling it is not.

Answer (score 0):

Worked it out! I post an answer myself in case anyone else has the same issue. Hopes it helps somebody.

I had to add the jquery.cookie library in my template.php

```
drupal_add_library('system','jquery.cookie');
```

And it seems you were right to add only one library at a time, Namari, it didn't work until I tried that. Thanks!